# Angular7 Mat-select intercept change

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

In my use case scenario I have a dropdown box (`mat-select`) which fills several input fields. Any change will fill the fields differently. Since the user could change a field I want to ask the user before the final change is executed if (s)he agree to clear(or change) all fields. In case of a NO the selection change will not happen and all fields should remain.

I tried to reduce the use case to a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhgfmx?file=app/select-overview-example.ts). I can select an item from the  dropdown and do some further actions.

```
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="intercept($event.value)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value" >
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

But at the time the `selectionchange` is exectued the content of the dropdown is already changed. For the [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhgfmx?file=app/select-overview-example.ts) I would like to have e.g.

1. Select e.g. Pizza
2. Popup appears
3. !The dropdown remains on the original selection and after the popup disappears a change happen!
4. Select e.g. Tacos
5. Popup appears
6. !The dropdown remains on the original selection (=Tacos) and after the popup disappears a change happen!

I have no clue how to intercept the change event **before** the change happen.

Answer (score 3):

We can't intercept the select `change` event **before** the change happens, because the `selectionChange` event is :

> Event emitted when the selected value has been changed by the user.

, as described in [Angular Material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect).

But we can trigger the update of the other form controls only **after** the user confirms it.

And, as **@liqSTAR** described, we must save the previous value of the selection and reset the select to it if the user cancels the popup.

A simple example would be:

```html
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedFood" (selectionChange)="intercept($event.value)">
```

```ts
selectedFood = '';
previousSelectedFood = '';


intercept(food:any) {
  const bottomSheetRef = this.bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet);

  bottomSheetRef.afterDismissed().subscribe( result => {
    if (result === true) {
       // update the the previous selected value
       this.previousSelectedFood = food;

       // update the other inputs based on `food` value
       this.otherInputValues = food;

    } else {
       // reset the selection to the previous value
       this.selectedFood = this.previousSelectedFood;
    }
  });
}
```

**Demo**: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhgfmx-9rzt7v

Now, the example above has an issue:

- in UI, the select displays the new selected value, when the popup is opened, even if the user has not made a decision :

[image]

In order to fix this issue, we have to reset the selected value to its previous value **immediately** after the `selectionChange` event fires, that let the user decide, and if it confirms the selectios, we'll update update the select accordingly.

The code would be:

```ts
intercept(food:any) {

  // at first, reset the select to the previous value
  // so that the user could not see that the select has really changed
  // we need a timeout to make in work
  setTimeout( () => {
    this.selectedFood = this.previousSelectedFood;
  }, 1);

  const bottomSheetRef = this.bottomSheet.open(BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet);

  bottomSheetRef.afterDismissed().subscribe( result => {
    if (result === true) {
       // update the selected value
       this.selectedFood = food;

       // update the previous selected value
       this.previousSelectedFood = food;

       // update the other inputs based on `food` value
       this.otherInputValues = food;
    }
  });
}
```

**Demo**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dhgfmx-xmvfvf

Comment: In principal this looks promising. I'm little bit reserved for this approach since it heavily relies on the current update mechanism in Angular. As soon as they change internally the solution breaks down. The update is done outside (and inside) of Angular. Hmmm... don't really know what to do with it in a long term view.

Answer (score 0):

Far as I know, you cant prevent this change. The only possibility is to save the old value of the selection and reset it to this value if the user cancels the modal/popup. I had the same problem a while ago.

Edit: Maybe this could help [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50236039/5677688)

Comment: Doesn't sound very promising... What a pitty if this would be the final solution,

Comment: Yeah, thx. But the use case there was that after choosing a dialog pops up and in a special case (when closing a dialog) the option should be set to the previous value. Somehow little bit different than my request - cuz I want to have it **before** and not **after**

Comment: I fully understand you. I wanted to check if the $event.value, which was an worker_id, if this worker_id was already in use. Needed to check it and by failure i needed to replace the selected new value to the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i do.

template:

```
<mat-select [ngModel]="something"
            (ngModelChange)="changeSomething($event, ngModelControl)"
            #ngModelControl="ngModel">
   ...
</mat-select>
```

code:

```
changeSomething(value: any, ngModelControl: NgModel) {
  if (<<false for whatever reason>>) {
    // reset mat-select
    ngModelControl.control.setValue(this.something);
  } else {
    this.something = value;
  }
}
```